# SUM of two columns over multiple rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets I'm struggling to write a formula to achieve the following:

With the sample data:

```
+--------+--------+------------+
| Status | Amount | Multiplier |
+--------+--------+------------+
| TRUE   |     10 |          5 |
| TRUE   |     10 |          3 |
| FALSE  |     10 |          1 |
| FALSE  |     10 |          1 |
| TRUE   |     10 |         10 |
+--------+--------+------------+
```

I'm looking to sum all the rows where status = true and return amount*multiplier. In this example, the end result should be 180, summed from the 3 columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use sumproduct.

See if this works:

```
=sumproduct(A2:A6,B2:B6, C2:C6)
```

Change ranges to suit.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter you data before, and then sum:

```
   A        B        C
  +--------+--------+------------+
1 | Status | Amount | Multiplier |
  +--------+--------+------------+
2 | TRUE   |     10 |          5 |
3 | TRUE   |     10 |          3 |
4 | FALSE  |     10 |          1 |
5 | FALSE  |     10 |          1 |
6 | TRUE   |     10 |         10 |
  +--------+--------+------------+
7 | Sum    |     *1 |         *2 |
8 | Result |                  *3 |
  +--------+---------------------+

*1: =SUM(FILTER(B2:B6,A2:A6))
*2: =SUM(FILTER(C2:C6,A2:A6))
*3: =B7*C7
```

See the [this explanation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) formula for this

```
=SUM(QUERY(R1:T6,"select S*T where R=TRUE"))
```

[image]

*Please adjust ranges to your needs*